# Visual Studio 2022 connection to Teradata ODBC Driver 17.10 from Server Explorer

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, teradata, visual-studio-2022, ef-database-first

I am trying to connect Teradata Database from Visual Studio 2022 through Server Explorer. The connection tested successfully but when I click on table to expand It gives out an error ERROR [HYC00] [Teradata][ODBC] (11430) Catalog name not supported.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iusi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg3Vd.png)
My question is if the connection established fine, why is it unable to access the Views or Tables from the Teradata database from Visual Studio Server Explorer. I also tried to Scaffold using EFCore but the models didn't get created, although the build succeeded.

Comment: As the message indicates, Teradata does not use catalog names for metadata requests. In the DSN configuration / Options / Advanced dialog, try enabling "Use NULL for Catalog Name".